# Safari Browser showing blur animation on an image for scale and opacity CSS animation

Tags: html, css, safari, webkit, css-animations

I was working on a hover animation on the web for an image.
It works fine on chrome, firefox. But when I tried on safari, the animation image is blurred until the animation is over.
[image: blur during animation]

[image: Properly showing once animation is over]

So I searched a lot on stackoverflow to understand what could be the mistake , but tried everything out , still no solution

html

```css
.hiddenStar{
        
        width:1px;
        height: 1px;
        position:absolute;
        top: 40%; right: 50%;
        transform: translate(50%,-50%);
      
        -moz-opacity: 0; /* Firefox and Mozilla browsers */
        -webkit-opacity: 0; /* WebKit browser e.g. Safari */
        opacity: 0;
       
        -webkit-transform: scale(1,1); /* Safari & Chrome */
        -moz-transform: scale(1); /* Firefox */
      -ms-transform: scale(1); /* Internet Explorer */
      -o-transform: scale(1); /* Opera */
      transform: scale(1);
        transition: all 1s;
        
      }
     
      #starspan:hover +.hiddenStar{
       
        -moz-opacity: 1; /* Firefox and Mozilla browsers */
        -webkit-opacity: 1; /* WebKit browser e.g. Safari */
        opacity: 1;
        
        -webkit-transform: scale(90,90); /* Safari & Chrome */
      -moz-transform: scale(90); /* Firefox */
    -ms-transform: scale(90); /* Internet Explorer */
    -o-transform: scale(90); /* Opera */
    transform: scale(90);
        transition: all 1s;
      }
```

```html
<p>
  <span className="text-brand " id="starspan" >Star</span>
  <img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/zerko/image/upload/v1634379420/Logomark_kxgewd.svg" class="hiddenStar"/>
  </p>
```

Tried webkit for scale & opacity, but still the same issue.
What I am missing here ?

Answer (score 1):

Zoom from `0.01` to `1` worked in Safari. but I don't know why... mysterious browser...

```css
.hiddenStar{
        
        width:90px;
        height:90px;
        position:absolute;
        top: 40%; right: 50%;
        transform: translate(50%,-50%);
      
        -moz-opacity: 0; /* Firefox and Mozilla browsers */
        -webkit-opacity: 0; /* WebKit browser e.g. Safari */
        opacity: 0;
       
        -webkit-transform: scale(0.01,0.01); /* Safari & Chrome */
        -moz-transform: scale(0.01); /* Firefox */
      -ms-transform: scale(0.01); /* Internet Explorer */
      -o-transform: scale(0.01); /* Opera */
      transform: scale(0.01);
        transition: all 1s;
        
      }
     
      #starspan:hover +.hiddenStar{
       
        -moz-opacity: 1; /* Firefox and Mozilla browsers */
        -webkit-opacity: 1; /* WebKit browser e.g. Safari */
        opacity: 1;
        
        -webkit-transform: scale(1,1); /* Safari & Chrome */
      -moz-transform: scale(1); /* Firefox */
    -ms-transform: scale(1); /* Internet Explorer */
    -o-transform: scale(1); /* Opera */
    transform: scale(1);
      }
```

```html
<p>
  <span className="text-brand " id="starspan" >Star</span>
  <img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/zerko/image/upload/v1634379420/Logomark_kxgewd.svg" class="hiddenStar"/>
  </p>
```

Comment: I have upvoted your answer. Since you found a workaround to make the animation still work with scale & opacity. I hope someone else can explain the reason behind this issue.

Comment: Safari seems to zoom and animate the image based on rendered bitmap instead of the raw image. you give the image  a  initial  size of `1px 1px`,  after zoomed out by safari, it looks like a big cube  in your screenshot. Just a guess, i did not dig into safari's source code, it's a laborious job.

Comment: it's not that, because once the animation reaches the Cap, the blur goes ( once it reaches the max scale value I provided), also when scaling back down, it becomes blurred again and continues the remaining animation

Answer (score 1):

You could try to add a will-change property to your element

```css
.hiddenStar {
   will-change: transform; /* or "scale" if you use this property instead of "transform" */
}
```